# installation of "mono for android" fails with "OSStatus error -67053" on Mountain Lion

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

I installed last night "Mountain Lion", which caused XCode to fail. When I installed a new XCode version, "Monotouch" and "Mono for android" disappeared...

I could reinstall monotouch quite fast, but I am unable to install "mono for android". After clicking on "Install MonoForAndroid" I get 
"Der Vorgang konnte nicht abgeschlossen werden (OSstatus-Fehler -67053)", which means something like
"could not finish this, (OSstatus-error -67053)"

All I could find with google was [1] which says that this could mean "errSecCSResourceRulesInvalid".

Anyway, I still have no idea what to do now. Is someone here able to tell me what I can do to get Mono4Android running again? Thanks ALOT!!

[1] = https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/CodeSigningRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 4):

The error -67053 means:

```
invalid resource specification rule(s)
```

I found one way to resolve this error: Edit the file Info.plist inside the application bundle and remove the CFBundleResourceSpecification property.

Answer (score -1):

In the settings is an option that you can only install apps from the Mac App Store. It seems that this option is turned on by default. To solve the problem you just need to turn it off.